# Вывод с запроса ajax

Tags: javascript, html

Есть ajax запрос на сервер, приходит json.

```
function SubmitForm(UserId)
{
    $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: ".../users/add/?usersid=" + UserId,
    dataType: "jsonp"
}) 
}
```

Как мне обратиться к пришедшим данным? Например вывести в index.html пришедшее поле lastlogoff?

```
"lastlogoff": 1511704052,
```

Comment: [документация](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) JQuery. Там есть такая "штучка", как success.

Answer (score 2):

Обратиться к полю по имени ключа, например

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: ".../users/add/?usersid=" + UserId,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data.lastlogoff); // выведет в консоль, но можно и в DOM поместить
    }
})
```

`success` - Функция, которая будет вызвана в случае удачного завершения запроса к серверу. Ей будут переданы три параметра: данные, присланные сервером и уже прошедшие предварительную обработку (которая отлична для разных dataType). Второй параметр — строка со статусом выполнения. Третий параметр содержит объект jqXHR (в более ранних версиях библиотеки (до 1.5), вместо jqXHR используется XMLHttpRequest). Начиная с *jQuery-1.5*, вместо одной функции, этот параметр может принимать массив функций.

Comment: А потом выводить                         <th>SteamID</th>
                        <td>data.lastlogoff</td> я правильно понял?

Comment: @MegaRoks зависит от того, `<td>data.lastlogoff</td>` - это динамически генерируемая разметка или уже имеющаяся, куда будут данные помещаться......т.е. например если сами формируете, то может быть, что-то типа `$('#div-element').append('<p>' + data.lastlogoff + '</p>');`

Comment: Я сделал как выше и мне в консоли выводит Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: @MegaRoks это не полное описание ошибки... и без визуального показа что точно вы делали - причин может быть много